# Alternative to Twitter API

Tags: python, api, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I'm working on project where I stream tweets from Twitter API then apply sentiment analysis and visualize the results on an interactive colorful map.

I've tried the 'tweepy' library in python but the problem is it only retrieves few tweets (10 or less).

Also, I'm going to specify the language and the location which means I might get even less tweets! I need a real time streaming of hundred/thousands of tweets.

This is the code I tried (just in case):

```
import os
import tweepy
from textblob import TextBlob

port = os.getenv('PORT', '8080')
host = os.getenv('IP', '0.0.0.0')

# Step 1 - Authenticate
consumer_key= 'xx'
consumer_secret= 'xx'

access_token='xx'
access_token_secret='xx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

#Step 3 - Retrieve Tweets
public_tweets = api.search('school')

for tweet in public_tweets:

    print(tweet.text)
    analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
    print(analysis)
```

Is there any better alternatives? I found "PubNub" which is a JavaScript API but for now I want something in python since it is easier for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want large amount of tweets, I would recommend you to utilize Twitter's streaming API using `tweepy`:

```
#Create a stream listner:
import tweepy
tweets = []
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
#The next function defines what to do when a tweet is parsed by the streaming API
    def on_status(self, status):
        tweets.append(status.text)

#Create a stream:
myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)

#Filter streamed tweets by the keyword 'school':
myStream.filter(track=['school'], languages=['en'])
```

Note that track filter used here is the standard free filtering API where there is another API called PowerTrack which is built for enterprises who have more requirements and rules to filter on.

Ref: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/overview/statuses-filter

---

Otherwise, if you want to stick to the `search` method, you can query maximum of 100 tweets by adding `count` and use `since_id` on the maximum id parsed to get new tweets, you can add those attributes to the `search` method as follows:

```
public_tweets = []
max_id = 0
for i in range(10): #This loop will run 10 times you can play around with that
    public_tweets.extend(api.search(q='school', count=100, since_id=max_id))
    max_id = max([tweet.id for tweet in public_tweets])

#To make sure you only got unique tweets, you can do:
unique_tweets = list({tweet._json['id']:tweet._json for tweet in public_tweets}.values())
```

This way you will have to be careful with the API's limits and you will have to handle that by enabeling `wait_on_rate_limit` attribute when you initialize the API: `api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)`

Comment: Thank you! But I get the problem (Page parameter is invalid)

Comment: I have updated my answer since page attribute is somehow in the documentation but not in the source code. It should work now.

Comment: If you want to try a different library, here is simplified example that both calls Twitter's search request and handles getting successive pages of tweets (until the tweets run out). https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/blob/master/examples/page_tweets.py

Comment: I'm trying to test the code but I keep getting (expected an indented block) I tried to solve it but nothing works

Comment: @user8423460 I just downloaded the code and it worked for me. The only place an indent is required is line 21 inside the `for` loop. Which line gave you the error?

Comment: @Jonas In line 11 (myStream)

Comment: @user8423460 I wasn't sure what you were trying, there was an indentation problem between the class declaration and the function after it, it is fixed now.

Comment: @Jonas Thank you so much :)